# UICollectionViewCell not visible but captured in view hierarchy

Tags: ios, collectionview

I have UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell. UICollectionViewCell's awakeFromNib is called. Cells are created and UICollectionViewCell's didSelect delegate works as per expectation. UICollectionView's scroll works as per expected. But cells are not visible. If view is captured in view hierarchy through debugging tool, cells are visible with proper data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us some code or screenshots atleast to understand.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: initially check the View hierarchy if it is fine then check the color

Answer (score 1):

As I had few wrong attributes mentioned in User Defined Runtime Attributes, view failed to render layer on screen with those attributes. This is the reason why cell were not visible on screen but captured on view hierarchy.

I got error on console because of wrong attribute on User Defined Runtime Attributes.
**Failed to set (layer.shadowRadius) user defined inspected property on (UICollectionViewCell)**
Fixing this issue solved my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you check by setting color of `UICollectionViewCell`? you probably set color of `UICollectionViewCell`'s color to white so it's not visible.

And if you set the color please let us know what you've done in your cellforitemanindexpath